# How to set column span for QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'd like to create a table like this:

[image: what I want]

But as for now I've only managed this:

[image: what I got]

How to setup the span in the second row to get this two spanned columns to have the same width as in the first image?

Here is the code of my table implementation:

```
MovableQtableWidget::MovableQtableWidget(const QString& text, QWidget* parent)
    : QTableWidget(2,3) {
    setWindowTitle(text);

    QStringList ColHeaders, RowHeaders;
    ColHeaders << "Name" << "DR" << "DT";
    RowHeaders << "Armor" << "Ammo";

    this->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(ColHeaders);
    this->setVerticalHeaderLabels(RowHeaders);
    this->setSpan(1, 1, 2, 2);

    this->setStyleSheet("\
        QTableWidget { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 255) }\
        QHeaderView { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 100) }\
        QHeaderView::section { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 100) }\
        QTableCornerButton::section { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 100) }\
        QTableView{border : 3px solid red}\
    ");
}
```

Comment: What would such a table represent? It seems the DR column may just logically need to be subdivided.

Comment: You can't do this simply with spanning: it can only merge *full cells* at given rows/columns, while what you want is to span *in the middle* of a column. The only viable option **could** be to implement a "spanning header" (see [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/22755171) and [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/12868693)) and actually use 4 columns: in the first row, the second cell actually spans between column indexes `1,2`, while in the second row the first cell will have a `0,1` column span, and the second `2,3`. Unfortunately, I doubt that would suffice, due to the way QTableView sets item geometries.

Comment: Both images seem to be identical?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote onw QTableView. You can download from https://github.com/PavelDorofeev/How-to-create-own-QTableView-with-new-capabilities

but this is for Qt 4 only still
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P59J.jpg)

[github](https://github.com/PavelDorofeev/How-to-create-own-QTableView-with-new-capabilities)